# jQuery toggle only one element instead of all

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have code that is using jQuery slidetoggle to show and hide specific lists. I'm wanting to click a plus/minus button to perform the event. But everytime I try to use the `a.minuslink` or `a > img` or `.minusimg` - I can't get any selector to work except ul. Can someone please help? Thanks!

**MY HTML:**

```js
  $("#xmlDiv").on("click", "ul", function(e) {
    var clickedUl = $(this);
    //alert(this);
    clickedUl.children().find(".mainlist").slideToggle('slow', function() {
      var img = clickedUl.find('span.minus img');
      if (img.attr('src') === 'images/plus.png')
        img.attr('src', "images/minus.png");
      else
        img.attr('src', "images/plus.png");
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="xmlDiv">
  <ul class="section">
    <li class="root">
      <div class="minus">
        <a href="#" class="minuslink">
          <img src="images/minus.png" class="minusimg">  
        </a>
      </div>Antivirus Compliance - <a href="../xml/xml/1 - Sample AV.xml">Download</a>
      <ul class="mainlist" style="margin-left: -25px; display: block;">
        <li class="desc"> <span style="color:#e4e4e4;">-</span>  <span class="desc_span" tooltip="Antivirus is not installed.">AV Not Installed</span>
        </li>
        <li class="desc"> <span style="color:#e4e4e4;">-</span>  <span class="desc_span" tooltip="Antivirus is not running.">AV Not Running</span>
        </li>
        <li class="desc"> <span style="color:#e4e4e4;">-</span>  <span class="desc_span" tooltip="Antivirus is not updated.">AV Not Updated</span>
        </li>
        <li class="desc"> <span style="color:#e4e4e4;">-</span>  <span class="desc_span" tooltip="">Compliant</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**MY JQUERY:**

```
$("#xmlDiv").on("click", "ul", function(e) {
    var clickedUl = $(this);
    //alert(this);
    clickedUl.children().find(".mainlist").slideToggle('slow', function () {
        var img = clickedUl.find('span.minus img');
        if(img.attr('src') === 'images/plus.png')
            img.attr('src', "images/minus.png");
        else
            img.attr('src', "images/plus.png");
    });
});
```

Comment: Replace all that code with a working inline snippet

Comment: On your 5th line, you are using `clickedUl.find('span.minus img')`, but your HTML element is a `div`, not a `span`. Try just `clickedUl.find('.minus img')`. That is the first issue.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. Your snippet example toggles the list.

Comment: Also, not sure if it is what you intended, but having the `slideToggle()` on the ul will ensure that it toggles each time you click the ul, including its children

Comment: See how nice it is when you use a snippet? always do that

Comment: @j08691 i only want it to toggle if you click anything inside of the `<div class="minus"></div>`, not the .mainlist

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the problem is most likely the traversal from the link to the `.mainlist`.
One way of doing so would be: `$this.parent().siblings('.mainlist')`

```
$("#xmlDiv div.minus").click( function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.siblings('.mainlist').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        var img = $this.find('img');
        if (img.attr('src') === 'images/plus.png')
            img.attr('src', "images/minus.png");
        else
            img.attr('src', "images/plus.png");
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myoq1k4e/1)

edit: altered the click to attach to the '.minus' div, basically the same, but without the need for parent()